# Display port monitor not recognized

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, displayport

I have 2 monitors: One on VGA converted to HDMI and another on display port. Both used to work fine but suddenly the display port stopped working but only when I tried to connect 2 monitors. It worked just fine if I only connect the DP monitor but now the DP stopped working entirely. I am using RTX 3060 and an LG ultragear monitor. I have been trying to find a solution for months but can't find one.

Comment: Try another DP cable.